# Reading from pipe issue

Tags: c, linux, unix

I am writing on a pipe 10 integers, so i call write 10 times and then i want to call read pipe only once and store the written integers into an array of size 10 and after that add all the integers from the array into a total sum. The problem is that i get only 9 integers after reading. What i am doing wrong?

```
int main()
{
    int fd[2];
    int total = 0;
    int result;
    int nbytes;
    int child;
    int subVector;
    int written;
    static int readSum[P];
    int partialSum;
    if(pipe(fd) < 0){
        perror("pipe");
    }

    for(child = 0; child < P; child++){
        if((pid[child] = fork()) < 0){
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if(pid[child] == 0){
            close(fd[0]);
            partialSum = getSubvectorSum(elementsList,child,P,SIZE);
            //printf("Partial sum: %d by child #%d\n",partialSum,getpid());
            written = write(fd[1],&partialSum,sizeof partialSum);
            //printf("Child #%d has written: %d bytes.\n",getpid(),written);
            if(written == 0){
                printf("Writting not performed.");
            }
            close(fd[1]);
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    close(fd[1]);
    int status = 0;

    nbytes = read(fd[0],&readSum,sizeof readSum);
    printf("Parent reads %d bytes\n",nbytes);
    if(nbytes > 0){
        for(child =0;child<P;child++){
            total += readSum[child];
            printf("Partial sum in father: %d\n",readSum[child]);
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("Failed to read.");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using nonblocking IO, invoke read in cycle.

Comment: I used read in cycle and everything got ok, but i am curious: why isn't working like this ?

Comment: What is `static int readSum[P] = NULL;` supposed to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ignoring the wisdom of the sage Rolling Stones and not accepting that you can't always get what you want but sometimes you get what you need.

(1) There is no guarantee all your children have run and written to the pipe before the parent tries to read.

(2) There is no guarantee even if (1) did take place that your read would return all 10 integers in one read.  `read` can (and often will) return less than you ask for.

One way to cover this is to have your parent `wait` on its children so you know they completed and then to read in a loop until you read everything you need.

Comment: With this approach a loop would be enough - the read will block if there are no data, but more is requested.

Comment: Btw, why replies are not interleaved? Are simultaneous writes protected from that?

Comment: @Basilevs, yes true.  I thought the wait would better illustrate why everything was not swallowed in one read.  Pipe writes on the fd are atomic up to writes of PIPE_BUF length.

Answer (score 0):

http://linux.die.net/man/2/read
Read returns available data, not the requested amount, use cycle and check return value on each iteration.